# How can i get drawingcontext to draw recatangle with strokes

Tags: c#, wpf, drawingcontext

I need to draw a dashed rectangle on selection of items in an itemcontrol.I am looking for a way to draw a rectangle by `DrawingContext`.We have got `DrawingContext.DrawRectangle` and `DawingContext.DrawRoundedRectangle`.But How can we give the properties like Stroke and StrokeDashArray of the Rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `DrawingContext.DrawRectangle` you should specify the `Pen pen` parameter which is used to draw stroke. So you can create the `Pen` instance and set the `Pen.DashStyle` property.